# CursorAdapter ListView refresh

Tags: android, android-cursoradapter

I am deleting an item from listview which is populated by using Cursor Adapter. Even I used notifyDataSetChanged().But it didnt refresh immediately.I could see the difference after come to this page again from previous activity.

Your answer is more appreciated.

Here is my Adapter code:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.remove:
            dbUtil.open();
            String delItem = viewHolder.cartProduct.getText().toString();
            Cursor Cartcursor = dbUtil.getCartID(delItem);
            if (Cartcursor != null && Cartcursor.moveToFirst()) {
                Cartcursor.moveToFirst();
                String strCartProductID = Cartcursor.getString(Cartcursor.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.CART_PDT_ID));
                dbUtil.deleteCart(strCartProductID, delItem);
                Toast.makeText(contextNew, "Cart Item " + "RowId" + strCartProductID + " Product Id" + delItem, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Toast.makeText(contextNew, "Deleted Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            break;
}
```

**UPDATE:**

MyFragment.class

```
dbUtil.open();
    cartcursor = dbUtil.getCartItem();

    txtCartCount.setText("" + cartcursor.getCount());

    if (cartcursor != null && cartcursor.moveToFirst()) {
        cartcursor.moveToFirst();
        cartAdapter = new CartCursorAdapter(context, cartcursor, MYFRAGMENT, true);
        cartList.setAdapter(cartAdapter);
        cartList.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
        cartAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

**PERFECT RESULT:**

```
  @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.remove:
                dbUtil.open();
                String delItem = viewHolder.cartProduct.getText().toString();
                Cursor Cartcursor = dbUtil.getCartID(delItem);
                if (Cartcursor != null && Cartcursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    Cartcursor.moveToFirst();
                    String strCartProductID = Cartcursor.getString(Cartcursor.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.CART_PDT_ID));
                    dbUtil.deleteCart(strCartProductID, delItem);

                    Cartcursor = dbUtil.getCartItem();
                    swapCursor(Cartcursor);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
                break;
    }
```

Comment: Show your code where you are calling notifyDatasetChanged()

Comment: Updated the code.Please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Use Have to Refresh Listview using Cursor.

You "refresh [your] Cursor" by running your code again to get the `Cursor`, using the code you used to create the original `Cursor` (on a background thread, please). You refresh your `ListView` by calling `changeCursor()` or `swapCursor()` on the `CursorAdapter`.

Comment: @ParamaSudha glad to help you.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks, try this approach:

```
        @Override
        public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
            return new CursorLoader(...);
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
            adapter.swapCursor(data);
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
            adapter.swapCursor(null);
        }
```

The key point is to call `swapCursor()` method with the new data